# Unable to get environment variable in .Net Core in Hosted environment

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

Below my code working fine in development environment.
But, when same code hosted in server, its not working correctly.

Also, i got created environment variable in server name "**ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT**"

insted of return actual environment name UAT or PROD, i getting **#{ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}** as a value

```
public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var envr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            Logger.Info("-startup -start");
            Logger.Info(envr);
            Logger.Info(env.EnvironmentName);
            Logger.Info("-startup -end");

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                //.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings."+ envr +".json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using ASP.NET Core's WebHost? What you posted *tries* to do what the default configuration does. The `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` doesn't have to exist. If it's missing, the environment is expected to be `Production`. It's a **bad** idea to hard-code a Production file though. Use the default behavior, use a main `appsettings.json` file and add overrides to `Development`, `Staging` or `Production` files

Comment: WebHost doesn't just use a default environment. It also validates the env variable contents and only allows Development, Staging, Production. This way, you avoid invalid environment variables, or loading an arbitrary settings file because something/someone modified the environment variable

Comment: `i getting #{ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT} as a value` how did you create the environment variable? If it was missing you'd get an empty string, not this. It looks like you used a bad script that stored `#{ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}`. That's the very thing WebHost guards against